# Separate to different column

Tags: r

That's my data:

```
1                   75,AAAAGAAAVANQGKK,[14] Acetyl (K)|[15] Acetyl (K)
2                  192,AAAAGAAAVANQGKK,[14] Acetyl (K)|[15] Acetyl (K)
3                                    3770,AAFTKLDQVWGSE,[5] Acetyl (K)
4  934,AAIKFIKFINPKINDGE,[4] Acetyl (K)|[7] Acetyl (K)|[12] Acetyl (K)
5 1012,AAIKFIKFINPKINDGE,[4] Acetyl (K)|[7] Acetyl (K)|[12] Acetyl (K)
6                1970,AAIKFIKFINPKINDGE,[7] Acetyl (K)|[12] Acetyl (K)
```

I separated it by commas, but I'd like to have all of them in a different column with a title of each column. That's what I did to get those 3 different columns from the whole data set:

```
tbl_all_onlyK$concat <- paste(tbl_all_onlyK$id, tbl_all_onlyK$Sequence, tbl_all_onlyK$modifications, sep=",")

tbl_all_onlyK$concat <- data.frame(tbl_all_onlyK$concat)
```

Maybe there is an easier way just to pick some columns from the data, not by the `concat` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select columns of a data frame by name, use :

```
tbl_all_onlyK[, c("id", "Sequence", "modifications")]
```

And you should really read an introduction to R to learn about indexing !

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks, I guess it's not +1 for the difficulty of the answer :)

Comment: @Shaxi Liver, I agree with juba's suggestion. You may have a look at `?Extract` and [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html)

Comment: Thx, was much easier to do by this way. I am new with R and trying to do everything on my own but it rarely works.